# How do I keep Google docs' Voice typing from stopping

Tags: google-docs, voice-typing

I turned on Voice Typing in Google Docs on my windows 10 laptops. I get the mic icon in doc and click it. It turns red and responds to voice commands.

It works great but if I stop talking for 15s or so, it stops listening. The microphone button still shows red (on). But I have to turn it off and on again to get it to continue "listening".  I've tried saying "resume" to no affect.